# National Zoo vs The Maryland Zoo in Baltimore vs Philadelphia Zoo

Tags: washington-dc, philadelphia, maryland, zoos

I have a chance later this year to visit one of the following zoos:

- National Zoological Park in DC
- The Maryland Zoo in Baltimore
- Philadelphia Zoo

Only considering the quality of the zoo (not distance, parking, or price). What is my best bet?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most objective evaluation you're likely to find is TripAdvisor reviews.

- [National Zoological Park](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g28970-d109242-Reviews-National_Zoological_Park-Washington_DC_District_of_Columbia.html): 4.0, 3800 reviews
- [The Maryland Zoo](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g60811-d109082-Reviews-The_Maryland_Zoo-Baltimore_Maryland.html): 4.0, 559 reviews
- [Philadelphia Zoo](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g60795-d144041-Reviews-Philadelphia_Zoo-Philadelphia_Pennsylvania.html): 4.5, 1489 reviews

Personally, I'd go with the Philadelphia Zoo even if it wasn't the highest rated because I see on Wikipedia [it is America's first chartered zoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philadelphia_Zoo) and that makes it a piece of history too!